# Null value stored when fetching binary data

Tags: sql, sql-server, varbinary

I've a table `Employee` with columns `Id(bigint)` and `DocumentContent(varbinary(MAX))` in SQL.

Now when I try to insert records in `Employee` table using XML, `Null` value is stored in table for files whose size is less than `1Kb`. When file size is greater than `1Kb` it is being converted into binary data and is stored in database.

My XML generated is as follows:

```
<MyDocuments>
  <Rows>
    <Id>62</Id>
    <Document_Content>104116116112584747495550464954464846495856485748471041161161129910810510111011646104116109108</Document_Content>
  </Rows>
</MyDocuments>
```

and Stored Procedure is

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[Proc_SaveDocuments]  
(  
 @XMLData as XML
)  
AS
BEGIN
Declare @propertyCount Varchar(100) = '',@currentCount int=1,@Id bigint,@Content varbinary(MAX)
SELECT @propertyCount = convert(VARCHAR, @XMLData.query ('count(/MyDocuments/Rows)'))
SET @currentCount = 1
     WHILE (@currentCount<=@propertyCount)       
     BEGIN 
     SET @Id = @XMLData.value('data(/MyDocuments/Rows[sql:variable("@currentCount")]/Id)[1]', 'BIGINT')
     SET @Content = @XMLData.value('data(/MyDocuments/Rows[sql:variable("@currentCount")]/Document_Content)[1]', 'VARBINARY(MAX)')

     insert into Employee values(@Id,@Content) --inserts null in DocumentContent column when file size less than 1Kb, else converts it to binary and saves it in database.
     SET @currentCount = @currentCount + 1 
     END
END
```

Any ideas why is this happening and how can this be resolved?

Comment: How many <Rows> in the 1k files that are inserting NULL?

Comment: @tale852150: It can be any number of rows,1 or more than 1..

Answer (score 0):

I assume XML does not understand "VARBINARY" format:

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML = '<MyDocuments>
  <Rows>
    <Id>62</Id>
    <Document_Content>104116116112584747495550464954464846495856485748471041161161129910810510111011646104116109108</Document_Content>
  </Rows>
  <Rows>
    <Id>63</Id>
    <Document_Content>654654654654546847435483797123954898327987329759873256327864929347623974311011646104116109108</Document_Content>
  </Rows>
</MyDocuments>'

Declare @propertyCount Varchar(100) = '',@currentCount int=1,@Id bigint,@Content varbinary(MAX)
SELECT @propertyCount = convert(VARCHAR, @XMLData.query ('count(/MyDocuments/Rows)'))
SET @currentCount = 1

SELECT @propertyCount = convert(VARCHAR, @XMLData.query ('count(/MyDocuments/Rows)'))
SET @currentCount = 1
WHILE (@currentCount<=@propertyCount)       
BEGIN 

    SET @Id = @XMLData.value('data(/MyDocuments/Rows\[sql:variable("@currentCount")\]/Id)\[1\]', 'BIGINT')
    SET @Content = CAST(@XMLData.value('data(/MyDocuments/Rows\[sql:variable("@currentCount")\]/Document_Content)\[1\]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') as VARBINARY(MAX))

    SET @currentCount += 1 
    SELECT @Id,@Content
END]
```

[image]

Comment: this also didn't work for me :(

This stopped converting any file to binary.

Comment: Have you tried this script? Does it produce the same result on your server?

Comment: yes i tried it, now for every file null is stored in table.

Comment: I did not ask to `insert`. I asked to `SELECT`. Try inserting following code before your `insert`: `PRINT '@ID = ' + IsNull(CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR),'NULL') + ' @Content = ' + IsNull(CAST(@Content AS VARCHAR),'NULL')` and see what result it will give you. Compare it to what was inserted.